# Sharepoint 2007 hard disk failure

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, sharepoint-2010

Tonight we have experienced an HD failure that does not make MOSS to start correctly anymore.

We have backups and we have a new sharepoint 2010 farm that we have configured last week because we were preparing the migration.

Any advice on how to proceed to move the content databases to the new farm?

Comment: Do you have SharePoint backups or SQL Server backups of all databases?

Comment: @Marek: yes. I have sharepoint backup of the content databases and SQL Server backups of all the other databases. I dont mind to restore the server farm anyway, I can create a new one. The most important thing is the content database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot restore SharePoint 2007 backup directly to SharePoint 2010 farm (if you try, you will get the following error: *The backup package you have selected is from a version of SharePoint that may not be restored onto the current farm*).

However, one of the `00000xxx.bak` files in the backup directory is a regular SQL Server backup of the content database. Open the `spbackup.xml` file and look for instance name, database name, path to folder containing database files to determine which file it is.

You can use this file to perform [a database attach upgrade](http://technet.microsoft.com/library/cc263447(office.14).aspx):

1. [Prepare the new SharePoint Server 2010 environment for a database attach upgrade](http://technet.microsoft.com/library/cc263026(office.14).aspx)
2. [Attach databases and upgrade to SharePoint Server 2010](http://technet.microsoft.com/library/cc263299(office.14).aspx)
3. [Perform post-upgrade steps for a database attach upgrade](http://technet.microsoft.com/library/cc263286(office.14).aspx)

Comment: Thanks for the references. I am approaching to do this work tomorrow morning!